# Submit Data and Display in on the next page in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have started using ReactJS for a front-end development project and getting stuck at problem. I would like to get the name of an user as input via an Input field after a question such as: "What is your name". After the user input their name and the user clicking i. e. submit, I would like a new page to load where the submitted name appears:i.e. "hello {username}".

For now, I was only able to code an input field where the user can type their name in, however, after clicking on submit nothing happens:

```
export default function NameInput() {
    return (
        <div className="convo">
            <div className="popup">
                <p>Let's have a short introuction. Hi I am XX. What is your name? </p>
                <form>
                    <label for="username">Your Name:</label>
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            id = "name"
                            name="name" 
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={message}
                            placeholder="Type in your name" maxlength="25" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: What are you planning to post that data _to_?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do you mean for example if I want to send it to a server? Sorry, I have just started working on a project with not much of background knowledge therefore I am very illiterate on frontend development.

Answer (score -1):

```
use useState to hold the name for you, when you click the submit pass the value of the state.

  const [stateName,setname] = useState();
  const nav = useNavigate();
  handleChange = (e) => {
  setname(e.value);
  }

  const submit = () => {
     nav('/newpage', state {
     name: stateName
  })
  }
```

and from the other page you can use useLocation to access the data

```
const newPage = () => {
  const {state} = useLocation();
  state.name
}
```